# Using NLTK in Xcode

Tags: xcode, nltk, wordnet

I need to tokenize and find some synonyms of words in a sentence in xcode. I know NLTK have some packages to do that. but NLTK interface is in python. Anyone know how to use NLTK in xcode? or any other way to use wordnet in xcode?
Thanks,
Ahad

Answer (score 0):

Unless their is a binding, I wouldn't think it would be possible/very easy to do.